# How to create an image with REST (Drupal 8)

Tags: rest, drupal, drupal-8

I can create/update/delete nodes on drupal 8 (beta 12) by a `drupal_http_request()`. But I'm not able to create a file/image and/or link it to a field of a node.

I added REST UI to enable the filetype for rest and set permissions even to anonymous. But I always get a 403 forbidden back.

Here is my Rest request. But I don't really know what my json should look like. I tried it with/without authorization,Accept and Content-Type.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my json/rest request?

[image: DHC Rest Request]

Answer (score 0):

Encode image using command tool base64 and use:

```
{"_links":
{
  "type":{"href":"http://drupal.url/rest/type/file/file"}
},
  "filename":[{"value":"input.jpg"}],
  "filemime":[{"value":"image/jpeg"}],
  "data":[{"value":"insert-output-from-base64-here"}] }
```